# Nothing is being appended(written) to my txt file from my python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

I have written a code where I am trying to pick out some lines from text files and append them to another text file;

I have a folder :

> E:\Adhiraj Chattopadhyay\NLG Dataset\FYP DB
>   I have several sub-folders in it, each of which contains a **text file**.
>   So I have entered this directory in my python intrpreter;

```
import os
path = "E:\\Adhiraj Chattopadhyay\\NLG Dataset\\FYP DB"
os.chdir(path)
```

I now created a file with read & write permissions;

```
file1 = open('file1.txt', 'r+' ) 
data = file1.read()
```

*Now, I have written a python code which is supposed to **walk through** all the the folders in **FYP DB** to search for text files in them.*
If **text file(s)** is found, the code searches the text to **extract all lines with the word Table in them**;

```
    for (dirname, dirs, files) in os.walk('.'):
        for filename in files:
           if filename.endswith('.txt'):
               for line in filename:
                   if 'Table' in line:
                   # print (line.split(':'))
                      file1.write(line.split(':'))
print(data)
```

The code is then supposed to write these lines to **file1**

> This is where I am facing my problem!

When I **print** the contents of file1 ( data ), there is **no output.**
When I , then open file1 directly from the directory, a blank file opens.

**Could somebody please help me with this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this the next day. Sorry for posting it late, I had been a little busy, otherwise.

So the reason why nothing was printing was because the list was empty;
                My code **was reaching the text files but was not reading them**:

I found this out by removing the if condition (

> if ' Table ' in line)

.
Doing so filled the list with **all the names of the text files.**

Here is the code that worked;
**( however the formatting is still horrible and Ihave been working on that)**
( I used

> os.path.join

)

```
lines = []               
for (dirname, dirs, files) in os.walk('.'):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.txt'):
            thefile = os.path.join(dirname,filename)
            text = open(thefile,'r' , encoding="utf-8" )
            #lines = list()
            for line in text:
                   if 'Table ' in line:
                       lines.append(line.split(':'))
print(lines)
```

This prints out the list.

The other provided some insight for which I am thankful.
I got the necessary info for my solution from https://www.pythonlearn.com/html-008/cfbook017.html

Answer (score 1):

1. It might be the ' ' (space) in between FYP and DB that causes the problem. Can you try to replace it with an underscore for example and see what happens?
2. `data = file.read()` seems to be placed at the very beginning, before writing anything in the file, so at that moment the file is empty. Printing `print(data)` won't show anything then.
3. There are two ways of dealing with file: open / close OR with ... as ...
   . If you go for the first one, make sure you close the file after you are done writing in it, otherwise it can causes problems (as not being able to read it). The 'with' statement open and close the file for you, it's the prefered way to deal with files.
4. Make sure you indented the 'for' loop correctly. Your post shows a for loop not correctly indented - is it the case in your code?

Comment: I checked your (1)- that's not the case.
The reason why nothing was printing was because the list was empty; My code was reaching the text files but was not reading them. I have posted an answer that you can check out. Thankyou for your response!

Answer (score 0):

Typically files are opened in Python with the convention:

```
with open('file1.txt','r+') as my_file_variable_name:
    my_file_variable_name.readlines()
    # or
    my_file_variable_name.write("hello world")
```

So that could potentially be the issue. It could also be an error in your code to gather the data, but if your `# print (line.split(':'))` gives you the expected results then that is likely not it. I would recommend you open all the files you want and store the data as a variable (Ideally a list so it will print better into the file). Then at the end once it is all gathered, just call:

```
with open('output.txt','w+') as my_file_variable_name:
    my_file_variable_name.write(data)
```

Comment: the reason why nothing was printing was because the list was empty; My code was reaching the text files but was not reading them.
I have posted an answer that you can check out.

Thankyou for your response!

Comment: Also even if you dont go with the convention;

```
with open(....):
   ....
```
The code works fine.It raises an issue with the file remaining open, but the code works.